# C++ Удаление объектов из массива указателей с помощью delete []

Tags: c++, указатели, наследование, динамические-массивы, деструктор

Всем привет! У меня есть массив указателей на виртуальный базовый класс, каждый из них в массиве указывает на какой-то его наследник, у которого собственно есть свой деструктор.
Если я использую delete [] для указателя на указатели(т.е. банально на этот массив), то сработают ли как нужно деструкторы наследников класса? Или только деструкторы, унаследованные от базового?
Вот что я имел в виду:

```
struct A
{
int a;

virtual ~A()
{
do some tasks....
}

}

struct B
{
int b;
~B()
{
do some other things...
}

}

//ну и пусть еще будет какой-то еще класс С ,который просто наследует А

int main()
{
B* myB=new B;
C* myC=new C;

A** array=new A*[2];
array[0]=myB;
array[1]=myC;

delete [] array;

return 0;
}
```

Сработает ли такое?
И второй вопрос, можно ли как-то без такого массива указателей обойтись? Чтобы вообще не было указателя A**, а просто был А* с возможностью записать любой производный класс в его ячейку?

Comment: А [написать код](https://ideone.com/R7Ue4S) и засунуть в компилятор слаб*о*? :) Нет, не будут вызваны *никакие* деструкторы, потому что деструктора у указателя просто нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементами вашего `array` являются просто указатели:

```
A** array=new A*[2];

delete [] array;
```

а для них никакие деструкторы не предусмотрены.

Грубо говоря, уничтожая указатель, вы не уничтожаете то, на что он указывает. Так что никакие деструкторы не будут вызваны вообще.

И это правильно :) — сами подумайте, что было бы, если бы вы были правы, а код был бы

```
A* myB=new A;
A a;
A* myC=&a;

A** array=new A*[2];
array[0]=myB;
array[1]=myC;

delete [] array;
```

Что до

> Чтобы вообще не было указателя A**, а просто был А* с возможностью записать любой производный класс в его ячейку?

то вопрос не очень понятен... Вас интересует это?

```
A* a = new B;
```

**Update**

> как сделать массив из множества разнообразных наследников таким образом? И чтоб не было проблем с деструктором для каждого?

Вариант с массивом и ручной работой :)

```
    A** array=new A*[3];
    array[0] = new B;
    array[1] = new C;
    array[2] = new A;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        delete array[i];

    delete [] array;
```

Вариант С++'ный:

```
    vector<unique_ptr<A>> array;
    array.emplace_back(new B);
    array.emplace_back(new C);
    array.emplace_back(new A);
```

См. https://ideone.com/9kSO0J

Comment: да, но как сделать массив из множества разнообразных наследников таким образом? И чтоб не было проблем с деструктором для каждого?

Comment: Ну делайте, как это делаете вы. Только вот перед тем как память освобождать - пройдитесь и уничтожьте объекты сами... См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: В последнем примере вместо `unique_ptr` должен быть `shared_ptr`. Иначе вы замучаетесь отвечать на вопросы в будущем. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да для меня до сих пор часто вопрос - что именно и где надо использовать... :)

Comment: Короткий ответ - везде использовать `shared_ptr`. `unique_ptr` нужен для специальных вещей вроде контроля времени жизни.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да я так и делаю :) Но вот если бы здесь, на ruSO, мне слишком часто не попадалось обратное утверждение — грубо говоря, что по умолчанию надо использовать `unique_ptr`... Вы едва ли не первый, кто вот так ратует за `shared_ptr`.